# Переносил сайт с одного сервера на другой, сайт на Nest JS запускаю его командой npm run start получаю ошибку, неверное значение для поля

Tags: javascript, mysql, nestjs

Также развернул учебный дамп, на MySQL 8.0.23 сверял типы полейв Бд, все верно без изменений, в чем может быть проблема ? так вытаскиваю данные [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получаю ошибку типа:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В каком направлении копать ?

Comment: *в чем может быть проблема ?* В кодировке.

Comment: Добрый день ;) Пожалуйста, в следующий раз отправляйте код и ошибку в виде текста(для этого есть специальные `{}` в панеле вопроса). Чтобы исправить этот нажмите `Править` под своим вопросом) Так, у отвечающих будет больше желания вам помогать и они сделают это быстрее ;)

Comment: Спасибо не знал